# leaflet GeoJson vs polyline

Tags: leaflet, geojson, line

Is there any real advantage in using `L.GeoJson` instead of `Polyline` when drawing paths in a map powered by `Leaflet`?

I know that `GeoJson` can attach additional options. It is also possible with `Polyline` but one has to extend it or have a wrapper object.

Our project needs dynamic addition and removal of paths. Can `GeoJson` still handle it?

Comment: When you say `GeoJson`, are you talking about the [`L.GeoJSON` layer group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) or the [GeoJSON data format](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html)?

Comment: @ghybs I am talkng about http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`L.GeoJSON` layer group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) is just a [Feature Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup) with extra methods specific for vector layers.

It provides a convenient conversion from a GeoJSON data object into a layer group made of Leaflet vector shapes converted from the GeoJSON data. In particular, a `LineString` is converted into an `L.Polyline`.

So your `L.GeoJSON` group is in the end just a container for your Polylines.

Therefore you can directly add and remove child layers like with a normal group (`addLayer` and `removeLayer` methods). You can add and remove child Polylines, whether built automatically at construction from the GeoJSON object, or added later on through `addLayer` (or even through `addData`).

If you want to shorten / extend a Polyline (through `spliceLatLngs` and `addLatLng` methods), of course you can also do it, provided that you get the direct reference to your Polyline.

Comment: Thank you @ghybs you helped me to choose. Instead of making our own wrapper we will use `L.GeoJSON`.